# What is $p+4 \pmod {13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$p=\sum_{m=1}^{12} (m \cdot m!)$, and the question is just the title.

I tried applying Wilson's theorem i.e $(p-1)!+1\equiv0 \pmod p$

but did not get much help. Thanks for helping

Comment: Is that $m$ times $m!$, or is it $m^2!$? Also, you have $\sum$ starting at $i=1$ but there is no $i$ in your sum argument

Comment: The first one.... Not the square

Comment: Sorry for the first time... Now edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\sum\limits_{m=1}^{12}mm!=\sum_{m=1}^{12}(m+1-1)m! = \sum_{m=1}^{12}(m+1)!-m! = (12+1)!-1$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:-**
$$\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{12}m\cdot m!=\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{12}(m+1)!-\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{12}m!=13!-1$$